# C# switch statement with curly braces for each case/default block within the switch statement?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

Typically, a switch statement in C# looks like this

```
switch (sh)
{
   case 1:
      DoThis();
      DoThat();
      break;
   case 2:
      DoThis();
      DoThat();
      break;
   default:
      DoThis();
      DoThat();
      break;   
}
```

But for the first time ever, I saw someone using curly braces for each case statement within a switch statement like below:

```
switch (sh)
{
   case 1:
   {
      DoThis();
      DoThat();
      break;
   }
   case 2:
   {
      DoThis();
      DoThat();
      break;
   }
   default:
   {
      DoThis();
      DoThat();
      break; 
   }  
}
```

Why are these curly braces `{`, `}` being used for each case and default blocks of the case statement above?

Why are they needed?

What is the difference?

Comment: They aren't needed. You can surround any code with curly braces to create a new nested code region.

Comment: also when you have a `switch() { case: }` statement... it makes it more readable to wrap around multiple statements..

Comment: I am aware that code blocks create nesting regions and limit the scope of vars but I do not see any reason for this in the switch statement above.  Thanks

Comment: @pixel There is no syntactical reason.  Probably a preference this person uses to make it more readable.  I prefer no braces myself.

Comment: @pixel So you understand the effects that a code block has whenever they're used, regardless of context, but have no idea what the effects are of using them here, in this specific context?

Comment: They can be needed when you declare variables in the block and want them to go out of scope outside the case clause.

Comment: I think it's stylistic. It's similar to people who always want to put curly braces after an `if`, even if it is a single statement. So, use it if you like it. However, be warned that I have seen incredibly heated discussions among developers for coding styles. :-)

Comment: it makes each case its own scope. I can therefore have `int xx = 42` in each one, this is my preferred style.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are not required, but they are useful if you declare variables with the same name in multiple branches:

```
switch (sh)
{
    case 1:
        var test = "test";
        Console.WriteLine(test);
        break;
    case 2:
        var test = "test";
        Console.WriteLine(test);
        break;
}
```

This will not compile, complaining about conflicting variable names. But if you add braces

```
switch (sh) 
{
    case 1:
    {
        var test = "";
        Console.WriteLine(test);
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        var test = "";
        Console.WriteLine(test);
        break;
    }
}
```

that will create its own scope for each branch and it will compile fine.

Some people get used to this and always add bracers, even when not defining any variables.

Comment: It always annoys me with code indenting that the `case` clauses are left aligned with the `switch` word. I like them as in your examples. :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue you sometimes face in a `switch` statement is that all the cases are in the same scope. That means (for example) that you can not use the same variable name in two cases. Consider this:

```
switch (sh)
{
    case 1:
        int result = 1;
        return result;
    case 2:
        int result = 2;
        return result;
}
```

This will lead to a compiler error, since you are declaring `result` twice in the same scope. You remove the error by introducing new scopes in the cases:

```
switch (sh)
{
    case 1:
    {
        int result = 1;
        return result;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        int result = 2;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Considering that `switch` cases are somewhat controversial, because they introduce additional complexity, adding extra scopes adds to the confusion. I prefer to use `switch` blocks in a way that does not lead to the described problem (by keeping the amount of code in the cases low and try to avoid large `switch` blocks).

In your example the scopes are not needed and I would not use them on a general basis, since this is "unusual" code. And unusual usually means confusing. Your question is a proof to that opinion (and it is an opinion, just to avoid a religious war here), since this construct confused you enough to ask the question.

Answer (score 0):

I belive this is remains of old code. I remember in C when I didnt put the break I would just fall in the next case...

This is no longer relevant and is just code style.

Note you can also do

```
switch (sh)
{
   case 1:
      DoThis();
      DoThat();
      break;
   case 2:
   {
      DoThis();
      DoThat();
   }break; 
   case 3:
   case 4:
   {
      DoThis();
      DoThat();
   }
   case 5:
      goto case 1; 
   default:
   {
      DoThis();
      DoThat();
   }  
}
```

The break will just leave the Switch but which will be left after leaving the bracket.