# defaulting to using braces enclosing each case in switch statements in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

In C++ or C#, it's generally a good practice to enclose each `case` within curly braces (e.g., see [C# switch statement with curly braces for each case/default block within the switch statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47419619/c-sharp-switch-statement-with-curly-braces-for-each-case-default-block-within-th)).

But **Visual Studio Code** defaults to creating a template that leaves them out.

What **UI preferences** can I change so that they are included by default?

[image]

Edit: I am not interested in a debate about whether adding curly braces should always be done or not, but rather knowing how to change VS Code's UI for this context.

Comment: you only need braces when you have local variables, otherwise it is only clutter/noise you add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a snippet by yourself.
Select Command palette (F1) -> `Preferences: Configure User Snippets` -> `C++` and add the following code.

```json
    "switch2": {
        "prefix": "switch2",
        "body": "switch (${1:expression}) {\n\tcase ${2:/* constant-expression */}: {\n\t\t${3:/* code */}\n\t\tbreak;\n\t}\n\tdefault: {\n\t\tbreak;\n\t}\n}"
    }
```

Comment: I don't see `Configure User Snippets` option in `Preferences` even if I search for it. I am using VS Code version `1.60.2`.

Comment: It is not in the UI preferences but in a menu opened with `(Fn +) F1` or `Ctrl(or Cmd)+Shift+P` key.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up slightly modifying @umitu's answer. Posting it here just in case someone else finds it useful as well:

```json
  "switch2": {
    "prefix": "switch2",
    "body": "switch (${1:expression}) {\ncase ${2:/* constant-expression */}: {\n\t${3:/* code */}\n\t} break;\ncase ${4:/* constant-expression */}: {\n\t${5:/* code */}\n\t} break;\ndefault: {\n\t${6:/* code */}\n\t} break;\n}"
  }
```

And now the default snippet looks like the following:

[image]